# При подключении библиотеки windows.h ошибка C2059

Tags: c++

Во время создания программы я попытался использовать функцию Sleep() из библиотеки windows.h после чего появилось 657 ошибки
E0090   использование функции, возвращающей функцию, не допускается sdffsdfsd   D:\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\um\consoleapi3.h    311

E0757   переменная "DWORD" не является именем типа  second  D:\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\um\enclaveapi.h 47

E0145   переменная "IsEnclaveTypeSupported" не может быть инициализировано  sdffsdfsd   D:\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\um\enclaveapi.h 32

E0144   значение типа "void" нельзя использовать для инициализации сущности типа "HANDLE"   sdffsdfsd   D:\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\um\memoryapi.h  204

E0145   переменная "TlsFree" не может быть инициализировано sdffsdfsd   D:\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\um\processthreadsapi.h  353

Если надо могу полный список скинуть;

После этого стер Sleep(500) и выводит ошибку
D:\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\um\synchapi.h(732,1): error C2059: синтаксическая ошибка: (
После этого заходя в другие проекты где испорльзуеться библиотека windows.h  выводит ошибку
D:\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\um\synchapi.h(732,1): error C2059: синтаксическая ошибка: (

Создал новый проект подключил библиотеку и все еще таже ошибка

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>

int main()
{
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Очень похоже на то что вы случайно отредактировали файл, и сохранили, после этого у вас и валятся ошибки.

Comment: Возможно, а как это можно исправить?

Comment: Запустить `Visual Studio Installer`, выбрать пункт, восстоновить.

Comment: Я сделал две попытки восстановления, но ошибки никуда не ушли